# I can't start virtual machines on my VirtualBox in Windows 7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

This was a fresh installation of the software and VirtualBox gives me this error message after starting a virtual machine I created:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine PinkiePie.
>
> The virtual machine 'PinkiePie' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Kobe\VirtualBox VMs\PinkiePie\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
```

I tried uninstalling it, installed older builds of it, downloaded certain dlls some forums suggested but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

In your VM's folder, look for 'VM_NAME.vbox-prev' file, make a copy, and rename the copy to "VM_NAME.vbox"

Comment: It still displays the same error message.

Comment: By any chance, do you have Avira anti-virus running? Try to launch your VM after stopping it if so

Comment: Its still the same, I'm afraid. Also I've noticed on the said log

`1038.1f78: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\user32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]`

Most the lines in the log has that "[lacks WinVerifyTrust]" and I'm wondering what this means? Should I repair/replace my system files or something?

Comment: Have you tried running VirtualBox as administrator? Next step might be uninstalling Avira

Answer (score 1):

Try freeing up memory by closing some applications, it worked for me without the need to stop anti-virus software or run VirtualBox as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling or updating VirtualBox - I saw the following towards the end of VBoxHardening.log

```
supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0xc0000190 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.dll'
```

Looks like VirtualBox.dll corrupted possibly?

Comment: this was it for me; probably after the same windows update that caused it for you!

Comment: Yeah I first noticed it pretty recently after that big update to Windows 10 in the last month or so - not sure why it would have stomped on VirtualBox but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Starter Edition:  it only runs three applications at once

You could be running into this limit.  The Start Edition has some other pretty strict limitations on it.